# A-frame dynamic body won't update it's rotation

Tags: aframe

I'm trying to add y-axis spin to a dynamic body in a-frame, and it doesn't work.

More specifically:

`console.log(this.el.getAttribute("rotation"))`

---shows updated values, but the object looks the same on the screen. What's going on???

Refer to this CodePen: https://codepen.io/mcanterel/pen/LroRYz

Comment: This might help you. https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/issues/240 I don't completely understand cannon.js so can't really offer a more meaningful answer, but they do seem to be discussing the rotation of an object with physics enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize the rotation with the physics engine using the utility function:

```
element.components["dynamic-body"].syncFromPhysics();
```

codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBKmry).

Comment: That's just what i needed. thanks! WHERE did you find that info?

Comment: @MCanterel i found it [here](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system/issues/78).